# PC Scanning and repairing drive (C:) and won't boot

Tags: windows, boot, laptop, repair

I have a laptop that is around around 5 years old. I was ripping CDs to the laptop and a notification appeared that said something about an error. I didn't pay any attention to the notification as I thought it was a failed update or something like that. When I started the laptop the next day, the laptop (Windows 10) started to boot but then showed a message that said something along the lines of 'Scanning and repairing drive (C:)'. I didn't think it was an issue until the laptop was stuck at a black screen with the Windows loading dots. I cannot seem to fix the issue and the laptop will not move past this loading screen. P.S: A few weeks ago I installed a programme on the laptop that was called 'Advanced System Care 9', and after using this programme my PC didn't start, but the issue was resolved and the laptop is working as normal, I have since deleted the programme. Would it be possible that this programme has deleted some important system files? Also, how do I get the computer to load, as it will not,due to the black screen and system loading circle. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You :)

Comment: Sounds like a HDD failure.  Replace and restore from your backups.  Without the exact error you recieved, which you cannot provide us, there is no way I can submit an answer to this question.

Comment: the "fixing" program is "chkdsk," and it can take a very long time (many hours if there are lots of errors scattered) if it is set to a "surface scan" so you want to plug it in and let it run. How long have you waited?

Comment: @Yorik A few days ago I let it run for about 4 hours. Although the laptop no longer shows the 'scanning and repairing drive message' it just shows the loading dots.